# Is there a way to add a library using the JAVA_HOME for the current project SDK in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

a colleague has a slightly different path to a java sdk library and a module uses it

I have had to put in a redundant entry in the .iml file so we both get it.

I would like to effectively use ${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar so as to remove the redundancy

right now it looks like this:

```
<orderEntry type="module-library">
  <library>
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_77/lib/tools.jar!/" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES>
      <root url="jar://C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_77/lib/tools.jar!/" />
    </SOURCES>
  </library>
</orderEntry>
<orderEntry type="module-library">
  <library>
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_112/lib/tools.jar!/" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES>
      <root url="jar://C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_112/lib/tools.jar!/" />
    </SOURCES>
  </library>
</orderEntry>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add it to the JDK configuration classpath instead. In IntelliJ IDEA project we also depend on `tools.jar` and there is a special `IDEA JDK` defined which has `tools.jar` in the classpath. All the developers configure JDK under the same name on their systems.

Another option is to use the [path variables](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/absolute-path-variables.html).

Comment: So I have a jdk setting in the project, so how to I get that path inside a library path definition in a .iml ?  as in $JDK_PATH$/lib/xxx.jar  ?? or something similar ?  do I use $IDEA_JDK$/lib/tools.jar ?

Comment: I tried <root url="jar://$IDEA_JDK$/lib/tools.jar!/" /> and that does not find it :O

Comment: Note: we build with different JDK settings to test different JDKs so a reference that changes when one changes JDKs is the desired thing.

Comment: JDK is referenced by its name in the project and inside JDK configuration you have tools.jar added to the classpath. This information is stored in the IDE settings and is not shared with the project.

Comment: can the sdk name be referenced inside the .iml fle? Or does one have to have each and every client configure the list of jars for it's sdk? "manually" we already have standardized sdk names. I can now say "install this out of the box" and assign it to the sdk name with no extra complications all the other jars and build tools are part of the project and in a repository.  The objective pretty much have a one click "dev enivornment" install, build and run, to get someone up.

Comment: JDK is referenced by the name automatically, your project does not store individual JDK jars.

Comment: Alas - does seem to be a "you can't get there from here" sort of thing :) So one needs to have a dev environment setup manual :)